# mysql like% query is slow with full-text index

Tags: mysql, database

I'm using a simple mysql LIKE query like this:
`SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE field LIKE 'aaa%' ORDER BY field2`

I have a full-text index on "field", and still it is very slow.
I understood there is an option to use match. What is the difference? How? What is the best approach for my usage?
Notice I'm using the "%" for everything that starts with "aaa"

UPDATE:
I've ended up using something like this:
`SELECT

*, MATCH (name) AGAINST ('a*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS SCORE

FROM

users
WHERE

MATCH (name) AGAINST ('a*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

ORDER BY SCORE, popularity DESC LIMIT 4`

One thing I would like to change, is not due the order by firstly by SCORE and then by my field popularity, and instead order by a simple weight function, something like 0.5*SCORE + 0.5*popularity. How?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`LIKE` does not use the full-text index. To make use of the fulltext index, you have to use match (as you said):

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable 
WHERE MATCH(field) AGAINST ('aaa*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY field2
```

The [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) has a extensive Chapter on [Full-Text Search Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html).

Comment: Interesting.. Does anyone have any equivalent queries for DB2 or sybase? Google isn't being much help.

Comment: @user606723 have a look at this article: [Full-text search with DB2 Text Search](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/tutorials/dm-0810shettar/index.html)

Comment: I've updated my query with an "order by". How can I add that?

Comment: @Noam the same way you would did in your query ;)

Comment: @Noam `ORDER BY (0.5*SCORE + 0.5*popularity)` should actually work

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is correct but I want to add that if you are just going to filter by a field **starting with** like this

```
WHERE field LIKE 'aaa%' ORDER BY field2
```

then a normal index would work.

If you want to search by contains (i.e. `field like '%aaa%'`), then you will have to use a full-text index as mentioned above.

Comment: As it stands, the answer should have been a comment.  Or you could have posted the complete answer.

Comment: I disagree, this answer is in a way more full and correct than the previous one.