# Php/MySQL: Alternative for selecting all products/rows?

Tags: php, mysql

My PHP application has the function `product_fetch([parameters])` which returns 'Product' objects which information are stored in database.

In my admin area, there is a page called "Featured Products" which allows me to select 10 products to be displayed in the main page.

Now comes the problem: I made 10 select/combobox, each allows me to select one product, out of 400. So in order to make all the options, a query has to be made: `SELECT * FROM products`

Question: Is it correct to make such a query, even though there's hundreds of rows?

Comment: Agree with lc, also to the OP, instead of having 10 select/comboboxes having 400+ records from which he to select, isnt it better to give a paginated list of products with checkboxes against each so that the user can check the ones he wants to show in the homepage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be much better of specifying *which* produts you want in the query and only returning those if you have no intention of using any of the others at all.

You can do this using many methods. A simple one would be using an ID field in an `in` statement like this:

```
 select col1, col2 from products where id in(1,4,12,5)
```

It might seem to make little difference, but what if your procuts table had a hundred thousand rows in it?

You could also have a flag in the table to say that the items are *featured* which would let you use something like this:

```
select col1, col2 from products where featured='Y'
```

Or you could even have a table that only has featured items (even just their ID) and join it to your main listing like this:

```
select
    a.col1,
    a.col2
from
    products a
        join featured b
            on a.id=b.id
```

If you want to pick through your whole table, you can even use a simple `limit` clause that picks up a certain number of rows from the table and can be reused to get the next set:

```
select col1, col2 from products limit 10;
// Will pick the first 10 rows of data.

select col1, col2 from procuts limit 30,10;
// Will pick rows 31-40 (skipping first 30, then returning next 10)
```

The short version is though, no matter how you do it, pulling back a whole table of data to pick through it within PHP is a *bad thing* and to be avoided at all costs. It makes the database work much harder, uses more network between the database and PHP (even if they are on the same machine, it is transferring a lot more data between the two of them) and it will by default make PHP use a lot more resources to process the information.

Comment: The way I read it, the OP has intention of using all rows. (Your query is good for the front page, yes, but that is not what the OP is asking...)

Answer (score 2):

The solution you proposed is certainly do-able, and 400 rows is really meek compared to the upper limits of what MySQL is capable of handling. What is more concerning is the user experience here. Granted this will only affect you, but I would design myself something a little nicer than a bunch of `<select>`s. My idea is to start with just one textbox that autocompletes the names of your products. This can be accomplished if the [product title has a fulltext index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695746/mysql-like-query-is-slow-with-full-text-index). Then your autocomplete script could use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST ('contents of textbox' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

There are plenty of jQuery plugins [like Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote) that will handle the JS side (querying the server for autocomplete results). The one I just mentioned adds a `term` GET parameter which you could easily grab and throw into the query:

```
// You might want to only select the relevant columns
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM Products WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST (:search IN BOOLEAN MODE)');
$stmt->execute(array(':search' => $_GET['term']);

// Output JSON results
echo json_encode($stmt->fetchall());
```

Once you type in (or click on an autocomplete result) in the one textbox, another should appear below it and the focus should go to it. From there you can type another product, and continue until you reach 10. Each textbox (unless there is only one) should have a delete link next to it that removes that product from the featured listing.

I'll look for a site that implements this kind of functionality so you can better understand what I'm talking about. Basically here, what you're searching for is achieved. You don't have to have 10 select boxes with 400 options and you don't need a  `SELECT * FROM Products`.

Comment: never read about the match/against commands in MySQL. Will do some research. As for the JQuery UI's Autocomplete plugin, I've used it before, not a bad idea. But since this is not such a complex application, I won't bother too much with the user interface, so I'll just stick with the 'select' method, thanks bud

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT $page,10;
```

The above query will select 10 entries from offset `$page`
Fetching all rows is a bad idea as you are using 10 only anyway. When your table expands to millions of rows, you will see a noticeable difference.

Comment: The way I read it, the OP isn't using only 10 - they're using them all.

Comment: He is using only 10 at a time, is what I gathered from the question.

Comment: Hmm, I read it that he's using all of them, so the user can select 10 of them from the list. (Well, select one 10 times at least.)

Comment: Pagination is not a bad idea. But it wouldn't look too good with 'select' elements. I'd have to make a 'table' for that. And I'm not using only 10, the user needs to select 10 out of hundreds.

Comment: You are displaying hundreds of rows on the same page? In that case, if the number if entries gets too large, the page will render slowly. If you are sure it will remain in the hundreds, the query isn't too bad.

Comment: I see. Yes I'm sure it won't reach a thousand, so I'll keep using it that way. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing fundamentally wrong with selecting all rows if that's what you mean to do. Hundreds of rows also shouldn't be a problem for the query in terms of performance. However, thousands or millions might if your database grows that big.

Think about the user - can they scroll through hundreds of products? Probably. If not, then maybe *it's the UI design at fault*, not the query.